# Managing subview when orientation change on iPhone OS 3.0

Tags: iphone

I am experiencing difficulties managing my view controller rotation.
Here is my app structure :

```
[Window]
---[addSubview:MainViewController.view]
```

My MainViewController's view contains an UIImageView which I need to rotate, this is my app background.

In my AppDelegate and MainController I overrided shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to return YES, but when I rotate my device nothing change. Even the status bar.

Should I manually apply transformation to my views when I receive UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification ?

In IB I set resize subviews to YES in mainViewController.view.

So I am a little bit lost...

Thanks for your help.

thierry

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` — notice the colon, it's significant in ObjC — and only in the current view controller.

```
@implementation MainViewController
...
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I dit it. But nothing rotate.